# Intellij IDEA X: any multicore settings to be tweaked?

Tags: performance, intellij-idea, multicore

I've got a nice Mac Pro with 4 cores + Hyperthreading. Are there any Intellij settings to be tweaked to take advantage of this? Either through the GUI, or by editing the `Info.plist` file?

I'd be especially interested in making GWT compilation/execution faster. (I already have  `localWorkers 4` set).

Thanks

Comment: If there is, I sure would like to know!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this will help, but it sure looks interesting:

http://www.slideshare.net/intelliyole/intellij-idea-architecture-and-performance